# Is it appropriate to invite professor/potential PhD advisor for a coffee?

Tags: phd, advisor, united-kingdom, communication, stem

I am an incoming master's (international) student at a UK university. A few days ago I sent an email to a professor who I really want to work with (if I can get into the PhD program there, to which I am planning to apply soon). He will neither teach a class nor supervise any master's student in the upcoming academic year.

I asked about the possibility to have a meeting with him online, and he replied it would be easier for us to meet after I arrive. I was wondering for my upcoming messages to request an in-person meeting, should I request to meet him at the office/department? Is it generally appropriate/polite to invite a professor/potential PhD advisor for a coffee, so that I would possibly have more time to introduce myself and ask for some academic advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it's not *inappropriate*, but maybe slightly odd / unusual. I am also not sure why a coffee house meeting would give you more time to talk than a normal one - if it matters at all you probably have less time since your meeting time slot would also need to incorporate going to and from the coffee house.

That said, I don't think you even need to decide on the circumstances of your meeting - just let the person know that you are now here and if they are still willing to meet, and they will probably let you know how and when?